# Bitmap in ImageView is cropped off the screen

Tags: java, android, bitmap, imageview

I'm working on an Android application that needs to download an image and display it inside an ImageView. The Bitmap is passed to the main java file and added to the image view like this:

```
comic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.comic);
comic.setImageBitmap(c.getImageBitmap());
```

This works, except that the left side of the image disappears off the screen. The ImageView is in a ScrollView, which maintains the correct size. This means that there is black space to the right in the ScrollView and the image is cut off to the left.

The XML for the ImageView is this:

```
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <HorizontalScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/comic" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/xkcdlogo" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

Any idea why my image is being cut off?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried setting android:scaleType="center" rather than android:layout_gravity="center"?

This will center the image in the ImageView without scaling.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the problem, however now images that are small enough to fit on the screen are aligned in the top left. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Use `centerCrop` instead of `center`. All options can be found here with very clear explanation: [ImageView.ScaleType documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html). Warning: in my Eclipse Graphical Layout visual editor, some of this scale types are not displayed correctly. Use the Force and trust the documentation, on real devices and emulators it works.

Comment: Is there a way to do this but be able to animate the image across without it being cropped?

Comment: I know this is a year later, but how can I get it completely full screen? Thanks so much

Answer (score 4):

android:scaleType="centerCrop"

Answer (score 2):

The solution that finally worked for me was to set the inner ImageView to have a fixed height and width larger than the largest image, add a lot of padding, and then set android:scrollX and android:scrollY in the xml to get the images placed where I needed them.  This fixed the problem with the images getting cropped in the horizontal scroll.